# How to find duplicate records count in mongodb

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, mongoose

How to find duplicate records count in mongodb

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Mongodb?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: im using mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I get that in `mysql`

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) c FROM table GROUP BY name HAVING c > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
db.table.group({
"key": {
    "name": true
},
"initial": {
    "c": 0
},
"reduce": function(obj, prev) {
    if (true != null) if (true instanceof Array) prev.c += true.length;
    else prev.c++;
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $group: {
                "_id": "$a",
                count: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $match: {
                count: {
                    $gt: 1
                }
            }
        },

    ]


);
```